# How to connect Outlook 2010 to Exchange 2013

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

I've installed Exchange 2013 on a computer running Server 2012 R2 on my local network.  I've set it up as a domain controller, using a domain that I own.

- I can send and receive email using Outlook Web Access from another machine
- I can TELNET to the server on port 25 from my main machine and get a response from EHLO
- The inbound SMTP email test at https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/ works fine
- I've installed Outlook 2010 on the server itself and it works there

However, I can't get Outlook 2010 to connect to it from my main computer (which isn't a member of the domain), even though when setting up an Outlook profile, I can see the server and the Check Name facility works.

I get this:

[image]

Any pointers or things to try would be gratefully received.

**Update:**

Ok, so earlier I added autodiscover.mydomain.co.uk as an A record to my domain, which allows me to use Outlook's automatic account set up.

It seems to have propagated now, and on both my main computer, and also a laptop on the network (wired and wireless respectively), the autodiscover part works, but then logon to the server fails.

Is this a clue to anyone?

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Since it was the logon that was failing, and I'd already eliminated firewalls as the cause, I thought I'd revisit my hosts file.

I added this... `192.168.x.y ServerName.mydomain.co.uk`

(where `192.168.x.y` is the static IP I've given my server)

Annoyingly, I had already added `mail.mydomain.co.uk` and `Servername`, but they are clearly not sufficient. So many wasted hours looking for that.... :(